# Filtering function for pandas - VIewing NaN values within a column

Tags: python, pandas

Function I have created:

```
#Create a function that identifies blank values
def GPID_blank(df, variable):
    df = df.loc[df['GPID'] == variable]
    return df
```

Test:

```
variable = ''
test = GPID_blank(df, variable)
test
```

Goal: Create a function that can filter any dataframe column 'GPID' to see all of the rows where GPID has missing data.

I have tried running `variable = 'NaN'` and still no luck. However, I know the function works, as if I use a real-life variable "OH82CD85" the function filters my dataset accordingly.

Therefore, why doesn't it filter out the blank cells `variable = 'NaN'`? I know for my dataset, there are 5 rows with GPID missing data.

Example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client': ['A','B','C'], 'GPID':['BRUNS2','OH82CD85','']})

    Client  GPID
0   A   BRUNS2
1   B   OH82CD85
2   C
```

Sample of GPID column:

```
0     OH82CD85
1     BW07TI20
2     OW36HW81
3     PE56TA73
4     CT46SX81
5     OD79AU80
6     GF46DB60
7     OL07ST01
8     VP38SM57
9     AH90AE61
10    PG86KO78
11         NaN
12         NaN
13    SO21GR72
14    DY85IN90
15    KW80CV02
16    CM15QP83
17    VC38FP82
18    DA36RX05
19    DD74HD38
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `==` with NaN. `NaN != NaN`.

Instead, you can modify your function a little to check if the parameter is NaN using `pd.isna()` (or `np.isnan()`):

```
def GPID_blank(df, variable):
    if pd.isna(variable):
        return df.loc[df['GPID'].isna()]
    else:
        return df.loc[df['GPID'] == variable]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really search for `NaN` values like an expression. Also, in your example dataframe, `''` is not `NaN`, but is `str`, and can be searched like an expression.

Instead, you need to check when you want to filter for `NaN`, and filter differently:

```
def GPID_blank(df, variable):
    if pd.isna(variable):
        df = df.loc[df['GPID'].isna()]
    else:
        df = df.loc[df['GPID'] == variable]
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because with `variable = 'NaN'` you're looking for a string which content is 'NaN', not for missing values.

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

def GPID_blank(df):
  # filtered dataframe with NaN values in GPID column
  blanks = df[df['GPID'].isnull()].copy()
  return blanks

filtered_df = GPID_blank(df)
```